# Denial against truth

Tags: perception, emotion, personality, intelligence

I do not wish to be controversial but this is the only place I feel I can ask the question. This question was asked on the history site but I am now trying to understand the psychological cause and effects of the following:

I was recently shocked to hear about a certain group of people denying the Holocaust, especially on Holocaust day a few weeks ago.

As I was listening to the arguments put forward, it seemed very clear to me that the people arguing totally believed it was a "hoax".

I also understand a film has been made about this after a very controversial court case who went all the way to the high court.

Can anyone explain why someone can be in total denial of a fact that can be proven.

Do they live in an alternate consciousness? Is it an illness? Can these people be turned back to see the facts... or dare I say the truth?

Comment: Out of interest, is the previous question you refer to [here](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/32358/20939)?

Comment: [This article](http://www.ideajournal.com/articles.php?id=27) might help with your question

Comment: No. It's not that answer. There's another but it's highly politicised. I am interested in the psychology for such strong denial

Comment: It is. That's what I am looking for.